# Mongoid: find all children documents of multiple parent documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, kaminari

I have the following 2 models in a Rails 3.2.13 app:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Search

  field :name
  field :description

  has_many :locations

  search_in :name, :description, :locations => [:name, :description, :keywords]
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :description
  field :keywords, type: Array

  belongs_to :organization

  def self.find_by_keyword(keyword)
    locs = []
    orgs = Organization.full_text_search(keyword)
    orgs.each { |org| locs.push(org.locations) }
    locs.flatten
  end
end
```

In `locations_controller.rb`, I have this search method:

```
def search
  @results = Kaminari.paginate_array(Location.find_by_keyword(params[:keyword])).page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

Using the `mongoid_search` gem, I can look for the keyword (the search term) in all the fields for both the Organization and Location models, and get all Organizations that match:

`orgs = Organization.full_text_search(keyword)`

But what I want is to return all the locations that belong to the organizations from the search result. The only way I was able to do this was to iterate through each organization, then push its locations to an array, then return the flattened array. In order for the controller code to work, I had to use Kaminari's `paginate_array` method.

My question is, is there a better way to achieve the same result without using the `paginate_array` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `organization_id.in`

```
@locations = Location.where(:organization_id.in => orgs.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much more concise.